# Replacing the words "Experimental and Control " from the metanalysis with the words (postoperative and Preoperative)

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I have run a metanalysis using the meta package and created the following forest plot. I want to replace the 2 words Experimental and Control with Postoperative and preoperative. How can I do that?

I have used the following code to create the forest plot

```
forest(MD_LYSHOLM,fixed = FALSE, random = TRUE, overall= FALSE, col.random = "blue", prediction = TRUE, pooled.events = TRUE, xlab = "Mean Difference in Lysholm Scores",fs.xlab = 14,weight.study = "random", col.study = "black", col.square = "red",col.square.lines = "black", col.diamond = "black",hetstat = TRUE, overall.hetstat = FALSE, hetlab = "Heterogeneity",resid.hetstat = FALSE, print.I2 = TRUE, print.tau = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: You will greatly improve your chances of getting a useful answer if you include reproducible code to produce a similar table.

Comment: do you mean just change the column names of the df?

Comment: I have added the code that I used to create the forest plot

Comment: Hi Andy, No these are not column names of the data frames. Experimental and control comes automatic when u do a metanalysis using the metacont function

Comment: `?metacont` shows how to change the automatic defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/meta/versions/4.9-9/topics/metacont), I found these function arguments

```
label.e
Label for experimental group.

label.c
Label for control group.
```

Edit your code to add these arguments in your call to `metacont`, which should follow over to `forest`. Alternatively you can specify them directly in your call to forest using the same arguments, i.e.

```r
forest(
  MD_LYSHOLM,
  fixed = FALSE,
  random = TRUE,
  overall = FALSE,
  col.random = "blue",
  prediction = TRUE,
  pooled.events = TRUE,
  xlab = "Mean Difference in Lysholm Scores",
  fs.xlab = 14,
  weight.study = "random",
  col.study = "black",
  col.square = "red",
  col.square.lines = "black",
  col.diamond = "black",
  hetstat = TRUE,
  overall.hetstat = FALSE,
  hetlab = "Heterogeneity",
  resid.hetstat = FALSE,
  print.I2 = TRUE,
  print.tau = TRUE,
  label.c = "Pre-operative", # Added this
  label.e = "Post-operative" # Added this
)
```